# Преобразовать файл в string или buffer

Tags: python, файлы, django

Загружаю .mp3 файл формой, POST запросом. На сервере не сохраняю его, а дальше пересылаю по FTP на другой сервер. В промежутке между этим посылаю загруженный файл в функцию, чтобы получить meta данные о файле (исполнитель, битрейт и т.д.), данные получаю с помощью eyeD3.

Если файл лежит на сервере, то все данные снимаю отлично, но если пытаюсь сунуть не сохраненный файл, вываливаются ошибки:

```
>>>eyeD3.Mp3AudioFile(file)
TypeError: 'expected string or buffer'
>>>eyeD3.Mp3AudioFile(file._name)
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: u'name.mp3'
```

Так вот, как же файл так открыть, чтобы не нужно было его сохранять, а сделать это на лету?

Вот данные о загружаемых файлах:

```
>>>file
<TemporaryUploadedFile: neme.mp3 (audio/mp3)>
>>>type(file)
<class 'django.core.files.uploadedfile.TemporaryUploadedFile'>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Видимо `eyeD3.Mp3AudioFile()` требует полный путь к фалу, т.е.:

```
eyeD3.Mp3AudioFile(file.temporary_file_path())
```

Comment: Там файл лежит в каком-то зашифрованном виде: tmpJNCNCu.upload
Пытаюсь как вы сказали, выдает ошибку: InvalidAudioFormatException: File is not mp3

Comment: Значит такой файл закачиваете, т.к. TemporaryUploadedFile не производит никаких манипуляций с закачиваемым файлом.

Либо у вас ошибка где-то в другом месте.

Comment: В папке tmp там все такие файлы валяются (подобного вида), какие я когда-то закачивал. Но я их не сохранял умышленно, я на лету передаю дальше не ftp и они все удачно заливаются. Была бы ошибка, на ftp бы тоже не залились. Подозреваю что с трекам, как и с картинкой нужно побитово разложить, чтобы потом делать с ним что-то в системе, но не могу понять как разложить музыкальных файл. Все же придется наверно сохранить, и после манипуляций удалить его.

Comment: это конечно глупо,  но а если переименовать темпорери файл в имя. mp3?

Comment: Не думаю что это хорошая идея, так как файл находится в подвешенном состоянии, и передается далее. Переименовав, я скорее всего испорчу его, и дальше передать не выйдет.

Comment: Всё получилось. Однако через другую библиотеку - "Mutagen". И там как рас таки прокатил ваш метод. Так что считаем правильным ответом. Спасибо.